# django template filter remove html tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In the following django template variable .Is it possible to remove the html tags via django template filters

```
 {{myvar|safe}}
```

The following would output an html like

```
     <div>sddfdsfsdfsdf sd fsdf sd fsdf </div><a>This link</a><img src="some source" />
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have you looked at [`striptags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags)? It would turn your HTML into this (minus the syntax highlighting of `This`, of course):

```
sddfdsfsdfsdf sd fsdf sd fsdf This link
```

But be aware that this template filter uses a [regex](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/html.py#L82) to strip out the HTML tags. [As we know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), regexes are not the right tool for working with HTML most of the time. If your HTML comes from the outside, make sure to sanitize it with a real HTML parser, e.g. [`lxml.html.clean`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html).

Comment: it strips out all tags and only leaves what would be considered ``TextNode``s in DOM-speak. So your image would be removed without leaving any traces.

Comment: I suggest to use `{{ myvar|striptags|safe }}` so that HTML entities, such as `&nbsp;`, are not escaped by Django but kept in HTML code and rendered by the web browser. Please note that the `striptags` filter actually strips HTML tags, not entities.

Comment: @Luca Can you reference what is meant by 'entity' (as opposed to HTML tags)? Thanks.

Comment: HTML entities are a series of numerical or character entities that encode some character that is not part of the standard ascii character set. This includes everything from ampersands & encoded as `&amp;` to quotes `&rdquo;` `&ldquo;` and [much more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML)

Comment: Beware that striptags does **NOT** protect you from HTML injection:
`Template('{{ s|striptags }}').render(s='&lt;script src="http://chezsoi.org"/&gt;')`

Comment: @Luca NEVER apply the safe filter to a striptags output. If you are looking for something more robust, you can use the *bleach* Python library, notably its [clean](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html) method.

Comment: @BenjaminWohlwend - It looks to me like the `striptags` method (at least in Django 3.1) relies on `_strip_once` which calls `MLStripper` which inherits from `HTMLParser`... I didn't look into that class, but it looks to me like a proper parser and it's not relying on some crude regex anymore, ten years after you posted your answer...

Answer (score 29):

striptags

Makes all possible efforts to strip all [X]HTML tags.

For example:

```
{{ myvar|striptags }}
```

If myvar is `<b>Joel</b> <button>is</button> a <span>slug</span>`, the output will be `Joel is a slug`.

You can also use strip_tags in your python code i.e. in a form.

For example, in a Form clean method:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address

    def clean(self):
        from django.utils.html import strip_tags
        cleaned_data = super(AddressForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['first_name'] = strip_tags(cleaned_data.get('first_name'))
        return cleaned_data
```

See [Django HTML Utils](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/), Also check out this simple [Django HTML Sanitizer App](https://github.com/ui/django-html_sanitizer).

Answer (score 1):

To strip/remove HTML tags from an existing string we can use the strip_tags function.

import the strip_tags

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
```

simple string with html inside.

```
html = '<p>paragraph</p>'

print html # will produce: <p>paragraph</p>
 

stripped = strip_tags(html)
print stripped # will produce: paragraph
```

This is also available as a template tag:

```
{{ somevalue|striptags }}
```

If you want to remove only specific tags you need to use the removetags

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import removetags
html = '<strong>Bold...</strong><p>paragraph....</p>'
stripped = removetags(html, 'strong') # removes the strong only.
stripped2 = removetags(html, 'strong p') # removes the strong AND p tags.
```

Also available in template:

```
{{ value|removetags:"a span"|safe }}
```

Comment: The `removetags` filter is now deprecated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/internals/deprecation/